# Can I use Windows 8 File History to restore file from another Windows 8 File History Image?

Tags: windows-8, backup, file-history

Let say, if my Windows 8 is down, or my computer hardware is damaged, and I must reinstall Windows 8 or buy a new Windows 8 machine.
Can I use the File History Image from old Windows 8, to restore my files, say MY DOCUMENT, DESKTOP....etc to the new Windows 8 machine?

Or I must buy other old backup solution, such as Norton or even back to use the Windows 7 backup?

Answer (score 0):

short answer: yes you can

long answer: there are two options.

1. When selecting File History destination, UI will show you if there are backups already. If you select one, it will make backups there and will allow restoring files from it via normal GUI (even older ones, which were made before first backup on new system).
2. Files in file history stored unmodified and accessible by normal means (for example by file explorer). So you can access them even without File History at all (from Windows 7 for example) with the quirk: no metadata (original files metadata is stored in database, and files in history location are partially renamed and have different from original dates/times).

Comment: That 1st point doesn't work for me. In some specific case I can indeed select the previous backup but the File History is not showing anything. Restore thousands of files and renaming them manually is no Option.

Comment: I've tried it multiple times on different systems, and it worked. However, there is a file database. If it or description `xml`s are damaged or missing, file history app will not recognize the history folder. I don't have a good solution aside, from, maybe a custom script to copy and rename the files.